# Laravel 5 – querying items by many-to-many related model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I've got a following many-to-many relation:

`attendees - attendee_tag - tag`

Now I want to filter attendees based on some tag value, so I've created this solution, which works well:

```
$attendees = Attendee::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
    $q->where([
        ['attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', '6'],
        ['attendee_tag.value_string', '=', 'Summer ticket']
})->with(['tags' => function($q) {
        $q->select('tags.id', 'value_type', 'attendee_tag.value_string', 'attendee_tag.value_int');
}])->paginate($pagination);
```

But I can't figure out, how to filter attendees based on more than 1 tag ... I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$attendees = Attendee::whereHas('tags', function ($q) {
    $q->where([
        ['attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', '6'],
        ['attendee_tag.value_string', '=', 'Summer ticket']
    ])->where([
        ['attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', '13'],
        ['attendee_tag.value_string', '=', 5]
    ]);
})->with(['tags' => function($q) {
    $q->select('tags.id', 'value_type', 'attendee_tag.value_string', 'attendee_tag.value_int');
}])->paginate($pagination);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! :)

Comment: You can use the `whereIn` function
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Hm, but how? Can you show me the example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe with separating the whereHas :

```
$attendees = Attendee::whereHas('tags', function ($q0) {
    $q0->where([
        ['attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', '6'],
        ['attendee_tag.value_string', '=', 'Summer ticket']
    ]);
})->whereHas('tags', function ($q1) {
    $q1->where([
        ['attendee_tag.tag_id', '=', '13'],
        ['attendee_tag.value_string', '=', 5]
    ]);
})->with(['tags' => function($q) {
    $q->select('tags.id', 'value_type', 'attendee_tag.value_string', 'attendee_tag.value_int');
}])->paginate($pagination);
```

Comment: I don't want OR ... I want AND ... and what do you mean with your "Eloquent many to many relation" comment?

Comment: In Laravel Model you can declare Many To Many relations : https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

I understand now about the OR and the AND, I think you will have to use some raw SQL in addition to the request you write

Comment: I'm using 'tags' in whereHas, so (of course) it must be declared :)

Comment: I figuerd it out ( I deleted my question)

Comment: I changed my solution, Have you tried to use two whereHas ?

Comment: Tried it now and looks fine :) Thanks!